# Discord Bot doesn't join voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

im struggling to making my bot get into a voice channel, i have already read alot of posts that are here and none of them has been able to solve my problem, im trying to get my bot to reproduce the voice of a yt video but it doesn't even join and i dont know what to do, here is the code:

```
import os
import discord
import youtube_dl
from random import random, choice, randint
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command(name="join")
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.join_voice_channel` was the discord.py method, not the discord.py@rewrite one. You now have to use [`VoiceChannel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceChannel.connect). If your bot is already connected, then you can use [`VoiceClient.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=move_to#discord.VoiceClient.move_to) (If you want only one player on your discord server).

Here's how you use those two methods:

```py
@bot.command(name="join")
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
```

**References:** https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=migrating#voice-changes

Comment: thank you so much! this worked perfectly fine, i really appreciate it.