# How To Connect Discord Bot To Voice Channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I **looked** all the questions about connecting discord bot to voice channel for playing sound purposes but I couldn't find the answer I need. I'm new to the discord library and didn't solve how things work so **when I try given answers** in site I mostly get errors like this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

**My code looks like this**:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()

token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
voice = discord.VoiceChannel

@client.command(name="join")
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

client.run(Token)
```

This is just the voice part of the code other send or event parts are working.

Comment: I saw this .join command at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62888711/10767584 thread.

Answer (score 1):

here is what i use, i commented it as i can

```
@ client.command(name='join',aliases = ['summon']) # CREATING COMMAND "JOIN" WITH ALIAS SUMMON
async def _join(ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None): # TAKING ARGUMENT CHANNEL SO PPL CAN MAKE THE BOT JOIN A VOICE CHANNEL THAT THEY ARE NOT IN
    """Joins a voice channel."""

    destination = channel if channel else ctx.author.voice.channel # CHOOSING THE DESTINATION, MIGHT BE THE REQUESTED ONE, BUT IF NOT THEN WE PICK AUTHORS VOICE CHANNEL

    if ctx.voice_client: # CHECKING IF THE BOT IS PLAYING SOMETHING
        await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination) # IF THE BOT IS PLAYING WE JUST MOVE THE BOT TO THE DESTINATION
        return

    await destination.connect() # CONNECTING TO DESTINATION
    await ctx.send(f"Succesfully joined the voice channel: {destination.name} ({destination.id}).")
```

BTW music and voice bots are really complicated, if you're a starter, better do easier stuff, like moderation commands and games.

Comment: Thaks for the answer but I am still geting errors which is : `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
`

Comment: remove the "self" argument from the function, this command was taken from cog and i forgot to remove the self.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def enter(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if not connected:
        await ctx.send("You need to be connected in a voice channel to use this command!")
        return
    global vc
    vc = await connected.channel.connect()
```

BTW, don't forget to install discord,py[voice] module. I hope it has helped :D